# creating an output variable azure devops from the Azure SQL InlineSqlTask task

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, yaml

I have this in yaml with azure devops :

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL InlineSqlTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Service Connection'
    AuthenticationType: servicePrincipal
    ServerName: 'xxx.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'xxx-Dev'
    deployType: InlineSqlTask
    SqlInline: |
     select name as username,
                  create_date,
                  modify_date,
                  type_desc,
                  authentication_type_desc as authentication_type
                  from sys.database_principals where type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER'
```

I need to be able to get the output of this t-sql command stored in a variable so i can use it later on in my pipeline. Any ideas how i get this output and store it in the variable.

I would usually use a powershell command to set the environment variable but obviously this cannot be done within this task.

Any ideas would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

I have sorted this out. So I can use a powershell script within Azure Devops so i can directly get the variable and then use the setvariable task to assign the output as an env:variable.

```
$query = "select name as username,
             create_date,
             modify_date,
             type_desc,
             authentication_type_desc as authentication_type
             from sys.database_principals where type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER'"

$clientid = "guid"
$tenantid = "guid"
$secret = "guid"

$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST `
           -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/token"`
           -Body @{ resource="https://database.windows.net/"; grant_type="client_credentials"; client_id=$clientid; client_secret=$secret }`
           -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$access_token = $request.access_token


$sqloutput = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $.database.windows.net -Database db$ -AccessToken $access_token -query $query


Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GetVar;]$sqloutput"
```